# Primary key ID field auto increment not allowing JSON import. PHP/PDO and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo

I am trying to import a JSON file using PHP/PDO into a MySQL database. It will import fine if there is no auto incrementing ID field but when I add the field, the JSON file will not import at all.

Table....

[image]

Id field set as Primary Key, Auto Increment.

Example JSON data...

```
{
    "name": "Google", 
    "uri": "https://www.google.com", 
    "description": "The largest and most popular search engine in the world",
}, 
{
    "name": "NFL", 
    "uri": "https://www.nfl.com", 
    "description": "The National Football League",
}, 
{
    "name": "CNN", 
    "uri": "https://www.cnn.com", 
    "description": "Cable News Network",
},
```

Here is the PHP/PDO code I am using to import the fields...

```
$jsondata = file_get_contents('http://www.somewebsite/?format=json');
$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

$stmt = $db->prepare("insert into bookmark values(?,?,?)");

foreach ($data as $row) {
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $row['name']);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $row['uri']);
    $stmt->bindParam(3, $row['description']);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should change:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("insert into bookmark values(?,?,?)");
```

to

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("insert (name,uri,description) bookmark values(?,?,?)");
```

or

```
$stmt =  $db->prepare("insert bookmark values(null,?,?,?)");
```